# unknown tag "plugin" in smarty PRESTASHOP 1.6.0.13

Tags: smarty, prestashop-1.6

In prestashop 1.6.0.13.

using pf_stationery theme if i go to authentication form (log in as a customer not as a visitor) then i log-in the entire site not work. Only error message I have is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty Compiler: Syntax error in template "/var/www/vhosts/***********.com/httpdocs/themes/pf_stationery/header.tpl" on line 114 "{plugin module='ptsmegamenu' hook='displayTop'}" unknown tag "plugin"
<-- thrown in /var/www/vhosts/*********.com/httpdocs/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 114
```

I've activated debug in defines.config

Maybe it is a problem with the version of smarty but i've tried an older version and still not work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end the problem was not related to smarty but in fact the user that i was using to login in the front-office has associated any group. I associate the user to the prestashop default group "Customer" and the problem disappear...